# Searching for a sci-fi short story read to me from a hardbound textbook around 1974-1976 so copyright was probably '60's

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, hard-sci-fi, space-colonization

The story was about people living on another planet (for whatever reason) that was always dark and cold except for one day every 100+ years or so when the sun shone on the planet for only a few hours. It focused specifically on a classroom of children. As the teacher and children prepared to go outside to experience sunlight for the only time in their lives one child was accidentally(?) locked in a closet (broom or cloak) and was left behind.
The story told of how everyone had fun outside in the sun, being able to take off their coats and feel the warmth of sunlight, except that one child, who was found crying in the closet when everyone came back inside after it became dark again.
This story could also be part of a longer story, I don't know.

Comment: All Summer in a Day

Comment: @Adamant - Yup; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Summer_in_a_Day - *"Suddenly, a girl catches a raindrop in her hands. Thunder sounds, and they start to cry and run back inside. At this point one of them remembers Margot, who is still locked in the closet. Ashamed, they let her out of the closet, standing frozen, embarrassed over what they have done, and unable to "meet each other's glances."
The precious Sun has come and gone and, because of their despicable act, Margot, who loved the Sun the most, has missed it.*"

Comment: Ray Bradbury's "All Summer in a Day" has been reprinted [many times](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58363). If you read it in "a hardbound textbook around 1974–1976", the nearest thing I can find is [*You and Science Fiction*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?55764) by Bernard C. Hollister, published by National Textbook Co., but that was a trade paperback.

Comment: Yes, this is the story I've been searching for. Sorry it was a Dupe question, though I did search this website before posting my question I wasn't using the correct tags. Thank you, again.

Comment: @KathyMcNally: No worries. ^_^ It's generally not a censure to have a question closed as a duplicate, especially with `story-identification`, which is so relative with people remembering different part.

Comment: FWIW, I first read it in an anthology titled "Tomorrow's Children" by Isaac Asimov when I was about 10 or 12. I found it a great read; many great stories by many great SF writers.